# Python tkinter buttons not working in desktop app

Tags: tkinter

I made an application in python tkinter but the buttons are not working.

I added "open" and "save" buttons to this application. Pressing the "open" button opens a file explorer. However, the file explorer does not show the .txt files on the desktop, and when I press the "save" button, it does not save them to the desktop. How can I fix it?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x400+50+100")
def open_file():
    file = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir="Desktop", title="Open File", filetypes=[("Text Files",   "*.txt")])
    if file:
        text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            text.insert(tk.END, f.read())

open = tk.Button(window, text="Open", command=open_file)
open.grid(column=0, row=0)

def save_file():
    name = fd.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="Desktop", title="Save File", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
    if name:
        with open(name, "w") as f:
            f.write(text.get(1.0, tk.END))

save = tk.Button(window, text="Save", command=save_file)
save.grid(column=1, row=0)

goback = tk.Button(window, text="Go Back")
goback.grid(column=2, row=0)
goback.config(command=lambda: window.destroy())

find = tk.Button(window, text="Find")
find.grid(column=3, row=0)
find.config(command=lambda: print("Find button clicked"))

text = tk.Text(window)
text.place(x=10, y=50, anchor="nw", width=1000, height=700)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fix the iindentation on line 7.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button a name other than "open" and fix your indention. Since you've not specified a directory/folder the files shown will be your current working directory/folder.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x400+50+100")
def open_file():
        file = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir="Desktop", title="Open File", filetypes=[("Text Files",   "*.txt")])
        if file:
            text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            with open(file, "r") as f:
                text.insert(tk.END, f.read())

open_btn = tk.Button(window, text="Open", command=open_file)
open_btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

def save_file():
    name = fd.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="Desktop", title="Save File", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
    if name:
        with open(name, "w") as f:
            f.write(text.get(1.0, tk.END))

save = tk.Button(window, text="Save", command=save_file)
save.grid(column=1, row=0)

goback = tk.Button(window, text="Go Back")
goback.grid(column=2, row=0)
goback.config(command=lambda: window.destroy())

find = tk.Button(window, text="Find")
find.grid(column=3, row=0)
find.config(command=lambda: print("Find button clicked"))

text = tk.Text(window)
text.place(x=10, y=50, anchor="nw", width=1000, height=700)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is that you are using `open` as a name for a button, which is confusing Python.  Rename it to something like `openButton` instead to avoid confusion.

```
openButton = tk.Button(window, text="Open", command=open_file)
openButton.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

As for the issue with not showing the `.txt` files on the desktop, your save function won't save a `.txt` unless you include it in the save name in your file dialog.  To fix this you could use the `.endswith()` string function to add `.txt` to your string before writing it to the desktop if the user doesn't include it themselves.

Do this in your `save_file()` function:

```
def save_file():
    name = fd.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="Desktop", title="Save File", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
    if name:
        if not name.endswith(".txt"):
            name += ".txt"
        with open(name, "w") as f:
            f.write(text.get(1.0, tk.END))
```

and fix your indentation :)

Comment: Yes, it has done....Thank you.I want to open txt files with this application I made. When I run the programme and click the "Open" button, it does not work and says TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable.

Comment: Change the name of your button as started in my answer above.